# How to work with KnowledgeSettings in a Scratch Org?

Tags: salesforcedx, knowledge

I've been having trouble running `sfdx force:source:pull` against a Scratch Org where I was able to setup Knowledge, Record Types, Page Layouts, Knowledge Article Permission Sets, and Several Data Categories. I get this error:

```
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Unable to retrieve file for id 60 (KnowledgeValidationStatus). This Standard Value Set is either inaccessible or not supported in Metadata API.
```

Here's my `project-scratch-def.json` file:

```
{
    "orgName": "Company Dev",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": [
        "LightningServiceConsole",
        "ServiceCloud",
        "ServiceUser",
        "Knowledge",
        "Entitlements"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "securitySettings": {
            "passwordPolicies": {
                "enableSetPasswordInApi": true
            }
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        },
        "knowledgeSettings": {
            "enableKnowledge": true,
            "enableLightningKnowledge": true
        }
    }
}
```

And my `Knowledge.settings-meta.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<KnowledgeSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableKnowledge>true</enableKnowledge>
    <enableLightningKnowledge>true</enableLightningKnowledge>
</KnowledgeSettings>
```

Answer (score 2):

Validation Status is a standard picklist available in Lightning Knowledge (Knowledge_kav).

Looks like when you add some new picklist value to this field the scratch orgs change tracking mechanism(learn more about this mechanism, read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/a-deep-dive-into-source-tracked-projects.html)) track it as Standard Value Set change.

This is a bug and hence your entire `sfdx force:source:pull` is failing.

I suggest you log a case for this so salesforce can fix it.

**Workarounds (any one should work. I have not tested this)**

- Use the .forceignore and list your field path for Validation Status there so when you do force source pull it does not try to retrieve.
- Find the sourceMember record for this change via tooling query and delete it. Check [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/a-deep-dive-into-source-tracked-projects.html) on how to do it.
- Or retrieve everything from your scratch org into your source control and deploy it to a new scratch org. Do not change the Validation Status Picklist.

Comment: Thanks, @Mohith Shrivastava! I deleted the sourceMember record as per your second bullet point and the pull went ok. I created another scratch org and tried pushing my source into it and I got another unexpected error. I just submitted a caseI wonder what steps I can reproduce with your 3rd bullet point. Thanks!

Comment: You can retrieve everything by using mdapi retrieve command. It should retrieve everything!

Comment: Thanks again @Mohith Shrivastava! I think I'm closer to getting this working for me and you're helping so much. Thank you! 

Comment: @ivatanDev can you share back your workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Tooling API -- find the standard value set and delete that SourceMember record that is used by Source Tracking in the org.

```
select id, MemberName, MemberType 
from SourceMember 
where MemberType='StandardValueSet'
  and MemberName='KnowledgeValidationStatus'
```

Then clear the source tracking in your local DX project

```
sfdx force:source:tracking:clear
```